# Issues with pyinstaller and pyproj

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to do an standalone application with pyinstaller. The executable has just build fine, but when I´m trying to do some operations with functions integrated on library pyproj, the executable crashes.

The script runs fine on Pycharm, so I think that the problem is that pyinstaller is not linking with some kind of library of pyproj.

May I have to do something special with spec file or another thing to specify pyproj on the standalone application built with pyinstaller?

This is the error that Ihave obtained:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 6, in
<module>   File "C:\pyproj\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\pyproj", line 343,
in __new__   File "_proj.pyx", line 85, in _proj.Proj.__cinit__
(_proj.c:1190) 
RuntimeError: no system list, errno: 2
```

This is my "main.py"

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

 import pyproj 
 print pyproj.__version__ 
 p=pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when using pyproj with PyInstaller, pyproj can not find the data files that are in the library folder.

The solution is to create a hook file, which will specify where the data files, so you can link them with our executable.

```
 hook-pyproj.py

 from PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils import collect_data_files
 datas = collect_data_files('pyproj')
```

The hook file can be located on "hooks" folder on Pyinstaller installation or using the order --additional-hooks-dir, specifying a folder in which will be located "hook-pyproj.py"

Comment: I created a hook file and put the folder of the hook file inside of the hooks portion of the spec file and I wasn't able to fix this problem

Comment: pyinstaller 4.0 (released [August 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201532/issues-with-pyinstaller-and-pyproj) comes with a new separate [`pyinstaller-hooks-contrib` project](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib), and the latter [includes the necessary pyproj hooks](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib/blob/826de93955861ecc4f9fb62a913d83bf915c7cde/CHANGELOG.rst#20208-2020-09-12).

Answer (score 1):

Just threading on the previous answer, since 2014 there has been some refactoring on PyInstaller and here is the correct import line for the hook file above :

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('pyproj')
```

Comment: I tried this, perhaps I am not using the hook file correctly, but I put the folder of the hook file inside of my spec file and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> from PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils import collect_data_files
>  datas = collect_data_files('pyproj')
> ```

- This didn't worked for me. There were some errors in the executable again.

But I found in another thread that the problem can be solved with this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import pyproj as pyproj
```

pyinstaller seem to have problems to integrate the pyproj module itself, but basemap includes pyproj and is not ignored by pyinstaller.

Just for update